# Implement abstract class in Groovy via delegate objects

Tags: java, groovy, delegates

Anyone have thoughts on the follow block of code? Trying to implement an interface or abstract class without actually having to manually type in the implementations. Seems that `methodMissing` doesn't quite do the trick? Possibly some sort of delegation mechanism I'm unaware of would help?

```
class Outer {
    private List<String> theStrings = []
    class Inner implements List<String> {
        // error because Inner doesn't truly implement List

        def methodMissing(String name, args) {
            return getTheStrings().invokeMethod(name, args)
        }
    }

    List<String> getTheStrings() {
        return theStrings.collect { it.toUpperCase() }
    }

    void someOtherMethod() {
        List<String> blah = new Inner() // warning for incorrect types without the implements
    }
}
```

I'm aware that Groovy doesn't truly prevent me from assigning the `Inner` class to an object of the wrong type, but I'm more wondering if there's a correct way to do this. In Kotlin, for instance, there's a `by` keyword to implement using a delegate property, but I'm not even sure that'd apply here.

Comment: So you mean implementing the interface without overriding the methods?

Comment: Basically yeah I think.

Comment: This is probably what you're looking for: http://groovy-lang.org/objectorientation.html#_differences_with_java_8_default_methods

Comment: Not sure I completely understand. Could you write out a quick example?